# Exponentiation program

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to do a fast exponentiation. But the result does not seem to produce the correct result. Any help would be appreciated. 
EDIT: Manage to solve it thanks for all the help.

```
        if (content[i] == '1')
            s1 = (int)(po1 * (Math.pow(po1, 2)));
        else
            s1 = po1 * po1;
        final_result *= temp;
```

Comment: `Math.pow(1, 2)` is 1.

Comment: `(Math.pow(g1, 2))` is wrong, should probably be `(Math.pow(i, 2))` and you probably want to reverse the string first

Comment: After your revision `result` is never initialized, so the result will now be always 0

Comment: I notice that thanks. Just revise the code to the current steps.

Comment: Confused as to what you're trying to do? Are you implementing the pow() method? Are you allowed to use Math.pow()? If so why not just do a Math.pow(G, X)?

Comment: I am trying to implement left to right binary exponentiation. It is an assignment. If i were to use Math.pow(G,X) straight away it would defeat the purpose.

Comment: I don't think you should be using `pow` at all.

Comment: I could change it later. I am still figuring out the algorithm I guess. Got to read again. Thanks for all the help. Really appreciate it.  I will take a look again tomorrow morning.

Comment: @LennonChia I think what you need is to sit down with a piece of paper and do a couple of these operations by hand. Then write down what you're doing in pseudocode. Then turn it into Java code. (A good way of doing this is to start with an empty method with the pseudocode added as comment in the method body. Then after each line of the pseudocode add the corresponding java implementation.) I know it's a tough task but you'll benefit a lot more of it if you work it out alone. It will also feel a lot better, I guarantee you that.

Comment: @biziclop that sound like a good idea I will try it out tomorrow. Trying to explain out the algorithm kind of does help in a sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [Exponation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

You probably want to bit-shift right and square your base each time you encounter a 1 bit in the exponent

```
int pow(int base, int e)
{
    int retVal = 1;
    while (e)
    {
        if (e % 2 == 1)//i.e. last bit of exponent is 1
            retVal *= base;
        e >>= 1; //bitshift exponent to the right.
        base *= base; // square base since we shifted 1 bit in our exponent
    }

    return retVal ;
}
```

A good way of thinking about it is that your exponent is being broken down: say, `6^7` (exponent in bits is 1, 1, 1) `= 6^1 * 6^2 * 6^4 = 6 * 36 * 36^2 = 6 * 36 * 1296`. Your base is always squaring itself.

Comment: @LennonChia: sad indeed. any particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

`temp = (int)(g1 * (Math.pow(g1, 2)));`

This basically just boils down to `g1`<sup>3</sup>.  I'm not familiar with this algorithm but this can't be right.

Also, as a side note, don't ever call `Math.pow(<var>, 2)`, just write `<var> * <var>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, starting with the fact that you are reading the exp string in the wrong direction, adding extra multiplications by the base, and not considering the rank of the `1` when raising the powers of 2.

Here is a python quick sketch of what you are trying to achieve:

```
a = int(raw_input("base"))
b = "{0:b}".format(int(raw_input("exp")))

res = 1
for index, i in enumerate(b[::-1]):
    if i == '1':
        res *= a**(2**index)

print res
```

Alternatively, you could square a at every iteration instead:

```
for index, i in enumerate(b[::-1]):
    if i == '1':
        res *= a
    a *= a
```